# SwiftUI: How to apply .clipShape to .hoverEffect?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipados

I’m using the `.hoverEffect` modifier. It adds an hover effect to my button when users have their mouse/trackpad pointer on it:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello world") {
            // Action…
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .hoverEffect(.lift) // ← Hover effect
        .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}
```

However, when I apply a clip shape to the button (e.g. `RoundedRectangle` or `Capsule`), the view is clipped but the hover effect isn’t.

[image: Button with a hover effect]

How can I have a hover effect that matches the shape of the button?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.contentShape(Capsule())` to change the shape of the hover effect to match your `clipShape`. Note that this modifier also affects the hit testing area, which is probably desirable in most examples similar to your own.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, the order of modifier can change the view's behaviour, if you want to solve this problem, make sure the `.hoverEffect(:_)` used after `clipShape`.

use the code below instead:

```swift
// declarations...
.clipShape(Capsule())
.hoverEffect(.lift)
```